# what does "()" syntax mean in python

Tags: python

I am learning Exception Handling in python and came across following code snippet : an exception class:

```
from flask import jsonify

class InvalidUsage(Exception):
    status_code = 400

    def __init__(self, message, status_code=None, payload=None):
        Exception.__init__(self)
        self.message = message
        if status_code is not None:
            self.status_code = status_code
        self.payload = payload

    def to_dict(self):
        rv = dict(self.payload or ())
        rv['message'] = self.message
        return rv
```

In this code, what does this line actually mean

```
rv = dict(self.payload or ())
```

inside `to_dict` method? What does `()` stand for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`()` stands for an empty tuple. On the other hand, `or` here acts like [null coalescing operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator) in `self.payload or ()` where the entire expression returns an empty tuple if `self.payload` evaluates to false.

```
>>> False or 5
5
>>> [] or (1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: here the check is if it is None but it comes down to the same thing anyway since None is False in boolean check

Answer (score 3):

From python shell:

```
>>> type(())
<type 'tuple'>
```

So it's a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=tuple#tuple).

Answer (score 1):

Basically what is happening is that as @turkus answered:

> From python shell:
>
> ```
> type(())
> <type 'tuple'>
> ```
>
> So it's a tuple.

What it is doing is checking if `self.payload` is not `None`.
If it is `None` the variable `rv` is equal to an empty `dict` if not it is equal to `self.payload`.